# Carrierwave saves object data to database instead of file name

Tags: carrierwave

Hi 
I just can not find out what is wrong with my code. I have two models Items and Images and relation between them

```
 class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :category_id, :user_id, :title, :description, :published, :start_date, :end_date, :images_attributes
  has_many  :images, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :images, :reject_if => :all_blank, :allow_destroy => true
  mount_uploader :name, ImageUploader 
end

class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :item
  mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader  
  attr_accessible :item_id, :name  
end
```

I call the 3 instances of Carrierwave in items_controller.rb to add 3 images to the created item

```
def new
    @item = Item.new
    3.times { @item.images.build }
  end
```

The view form looks like this :

```
<%= f.fields_for :images  do |builder| %>
   <p> <%= builder.text_field :name  %> </p>
 <% end %>
```

Which resoults in this randered code :
 `<input id="item_images_attributes_0_name" name="item[images_attributes][0][name]" type="file">`

When Add and save the new item i **get object data saved**  instead of  **file name** ( suit.jpg ) in my database :

```
--- !ruby/object:ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile 
content_type: image/jpeg
headers: |
  Content-Disposition: form-data; name="item[images_attributes][0][name]"; filename="suit.jpg"
  Content-Type: image/jpeg

original_filename: suit.jpg
tempfile: !ru
```

Screen shot from database table below :

https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/_USg4QWvHRS0/TXDT0Fn-NuI/AAAAAAAAHL8/91Qgyp5jK3Q/carrierwave-objest-database-saved.jpg

**Is anyone who have an idea how to solve it ?**

Comment: I tried something like this but it doesn't work to  `  <%= f.fields_for :images  do |builder| %>
  <p>
    <%= builder.file_field  (@item.images.name).to_s %>
  </p>
  
  <% end %>`

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue, I wanted to create my own filenames (identifiers) so I defined a filename method on the uploader (in your case ImageUploader)
e.g.

```
def filename
  @name ||= "foo"
end
```

Answer (score 1):

First things first, Your mounting your uploader to a column named :image but from your pic of your db you dont have a column with said name.

1: Make a column for images called image ("since thats what your uploading.")

```
rails g migration add_image_to_images image:string
rake db:migrate
```

2: Update your model's attr_accessible to use the new column.

```
class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :item
  mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader  
  attr_accessible :item_id, :name, :image  
end
```

3: Update your view

```
<%= f.fields_for :images  do |builder| %>
  <p> 
    <%= builder.text_field :name  %>
    <%= builder.file_field :image  %> 
  </p>      
<% end %>
```

4: remove the unused mount from the Item class.

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :category_id, :user_id, :title, :description, :published, :start_date, :end_date, :images_attributes
  has_many  :images, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :images, :reject_if => :all_blank, :allow_destroy => true
end
```

I left :name in place on Image for use as an arbitrary value you can add to your image.

Also by abstracting your image model like you did I would also assume you want to keep track of the image order so maybe an extra column for that would be a good idea too.

Hope this helps.